# Firefox 47.0 to crash on startup selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, firefox, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

Yesterday we updated Firefox 47.0 and selenium test script started getting crash,

Please see attached screenshot. 
[Firefox getting crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBFYF.jpg)
as mentioned in Firefox release notes they suggested to use Marionette WebDriver . We have downloaded Marionette WebDriver for windows and as mentioned in [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver#Setting_up_the_Marionette_executable) we made code changes by adding Marionette WebDriver in bin/debug folder.Below are code changes for same

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions());
```

However we are facing issue "entity not found"

Note : We are using c# selenium WebDriver on Windows7 64 bit OS and We tired below solution  such as

- Renamed Marionette WebDriver to wires.exe
- Add Marionette WebDriver exe path in Environment variable.
- Use RemoteWebDriver as shown below

  ```
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();

      // Set Marionette on so the Grid will use this instead of normal FirefoxDriver

      capabilities.SetCapability("marionette", true);


      var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
  ```

Please somebody help in this issue.

Comment: What is the host machine? I would download and use an older version you know will work until you figure this out.

Comment: We are using Windows 7 64bit machine , Updated in Question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue, the problem is unclear for now, but this kind of situation was before, you just need to wait new selenium update or Firefox fix (depends who introduced this problem), for now you could revert to previous version of FireFox.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox

**UPD:** Now if you using Firefox 47 you need to use new FirefoxDriver(geckodriver),
Details could be found here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

Comment: Thanks for advise , actually we are testing on older version, but if you have any updated for new version please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add wires.exe to your System Path, not bin/debug. The Mozilla marionette instruction page does not mention bin/debug at all. Also make sure the executable is present on the path for the system your grid hub and grid nodes are running on, not just the system where the tests are running.